# Adding class if aria-expanded === true

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I go about toggling a class if `aria=expanded === true`? I have the following markup:

**html**

```
<a id="{{content.static.productDetailsToggleId}}" class="collapsed pdp-accord-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">{{content.static.productDetailsText}}<img class="accordion-plus" src="{{meta.assetsPath}}img/plus79.png" alt="accordion content">
</a>
```

**js**

```
$(function () {
  if ($('pdp-accord-toggle').attr('aria-expanded') === true) {
    $(this).find(".accordion-plus").toggleClass("accordion-minus");
  }
})
```

**edit - more info**

Basically I watch to switch between a `plus` icon and a `minus` icon, replacing the `img` in the `.accordion-class` with `content: url(another image);`. Here is my CSS as well.

**css**

```
.accordion-plus {
  height: 1em;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.accordion-minus {
  opacity: .5;
  content: url(../../assets/img/minus-1.png);
}
```

Comment: if ($('.pdp-accord-toggle').attr('aria-expanded') === true)  may b id issue/.?   use by #  is it id or what,?>

Answer (score 18):

looks like you're just missing the class prefix on the selector

```
  if ($('.pdp-accord-toggle').attr('aria-expanded') === "true") {
  }
```

it returns a string aswell, so wrap the true in quotes

Answer (score 2):

this would be easier

```
$("#pdp-accord-toggle[aria-expanded='true']").find(".accordion-plus")
```